# jQuery sortable fails with overflow: auto;

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, qcubed

I've developed a form that uses the jQuery sortable.  The form has several other jQuery and general javascript scripts.  I have specified overflow:auto; for the parent div of the sortable list.  Everything works very well on my WAMP development installation (on WinXP).  However, when I move it to a hosted server (Linux), the sortable list fails, when the list causes scrolling. The scroll bar appears and the list is scrollable, but is no longer sortable.

Not only does the sortable list stop working, all other jQuery and general javascript scripts have disappeared and, of course, no longer work.

I'm using jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js and jquery-1.4.2.min.js. The application is developed using QCubed 2.0 framework.

Any ideas on what would cause this will be very much appreciated!

Thanks,

LaCeja

Edit:

Ben, thanks for your reply.

I've been doing a lot of testing with this over the past couple of days.  What I discovered is that it is actually the size of the page that is causing the problem. For example, if I add more data in other controls and have a shorter sortable list, that does not cause scrolling, I get the same failure.  Actually, using Firebug, I discovered that my javascripts, which are all at the end of my page, are getting chopped off and I'm getting no 404's. This certainly sounds like a hosting problem. However, after complaining to them, they said they have removed all limits on my site and the problem persists.  My research led me to suspect they might have limitreqestbody installed and set, but they say no.  They're running CentOS. I'm really stumped by this one.

Anyway, thanks again for you response.  If you have any more ideas, please pass them along. I'm trying another host later today and will post the results here.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like a hosting environment problem than a code problem.  When viewing the hosted site in a browser, make sure that none of your scripts are 404ing.  In Firefox, you can use FireBug for this; in any browser, you can View Source and manually copy-and-paste the URLs into the address bar.